# UIImage from URL not appearing in async block in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to set an image from a url to a UIImage using async blocks. I currently have one model class which is a wrapper for an API I built, which returns the url of the image. My View Controller's viewDidLoad function calls the method in my API model class, then, the API model class finds the url and calls a delegate method from my View Controller, printed below:

```
    func didReceiveNearPeopleResults(results: NSDictionary) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
        var full_url = "http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/fake/112.jpg"
        var url = NSURL.URLWithString(full_url)
        var err: NSError?
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var urlConnection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
        var image: UIImage?
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            var imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.picture.image = image

        })

    })


}
```

However, the 'picture' in my view is not updated when the app runs. For debugging purposes, I hardcoded the url that should be in the image. If I assign the same code to a button, it works fine, and the image appears. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have several things wrong in your code, so I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. sendAsynchronousRequest is all you need to get your image. Since that method is asynchronous, there's no need for the dispatch_async call. You also have two other calls that aren't needed -- you set up a `NSURLConnection`, and then don't so anything with it. You also have `dataWithContentsOfURL:` which you also don't do anything with. Your code should be simplified to,

```
func didReceiveNearPeopleResults(results: NSDictionary) {
        var full_url = "http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/fake/112.jpg"
        var url = NSURL.URLWithString(full_url)
        var image: UIImage?
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.picture.image = image

        })
    }
```

If this doesn't work, then you should put a log in the method to make sure that it's even being called. The fact that your code works inside a button action method, but not here, implies that maybe this delegate method isn't being called.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the image in main queue:

```
 ...
 image = UIImage(data: data)

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.picture.image = image
 }
```

Comment: This is right. UI operations need to be called on main thread and NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest's completion handler may not be called on main thread.